# Find deepest child, :contains(string)

Tags: jquery

When I use the `:contains` selector, it returns all elements (including parents/ancestors) matching the selector. How can I just return the *child-most/deepest* element that matches?

Example:

```
<div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>more text</div>
    <div>
        even more text
        <div>Copyright 2013</div> <!-- I only want this div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
console.log($(':contains(Copyright)'));
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/rQ7qP/

I don't know anything about the containing page, i.e. It could be in any element type, or with any class/id attribute. Nothing can be assumed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
console.log($(':contains(Copyright):not(:has(*))'));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sMuda/)

Comment: I know, but I really can't assume the element type. Perhaps it will be a `span` or other element type

Comment: This works for the example in the question, but would fail if the div containing the desired string also had child elements. To get around this, don't select against elements that have any children; select against elements that have children that contain the searched string: `:contains(x):not(:has(:contains(x)))`